# How to add "edit" icon as a button to <Image> component in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I wanna add an "Edit" button with an icon in my `<Image>` component. following is my code for the `<View>` that contain the image.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
        style={{
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingVertical: 10
        }}
    >
        <Image
            source={{ uri: 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/test@user.i.png' }}
            style={{
                marginLeft: 10, width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50
            }}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

it is much better if i can do this, without replacing `<ListItem>` with `<Image>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like:

```
       <View>
        <Image
            source={{ uri: 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/test@user.i.png' }}
            style={{
                marginLeft: 10, width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50
            }}
        />
      <Icon name={'edit'} containerStyle={styles.icon} onPress={console.log('I was clicked')}/>
     </View>
```

Then the icon style like below: Note the `absolute` position attribute

```
icon: {
 backgroundColor: '#ccc',
 position: 'absolute',
 right: 0,
 bottom: 0
}
```

Tested with `Icon` from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html) but I guess it should work with any other Icon.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **ImageBackground** to wrap your icon inside it and for icon purpose use react-native-vector-icon library.

```
<ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Icon
    name="edit"
    size={18}
    onPress={this.edit}
  >
    Edit
</Icon>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to add an icon within the view which contains image. You can also add an icon button component using that library which will look something like this

```
<Icon.Button
    name="edit"
    backgroundColor="#3b5998"
    onPress={this.edit}
  >
    Edit
</Icon.Button>
```